# MySQL Select records for each date in month even if records does not exist for specific date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table with records having created_date field. I want to select records for each date in current month, even if there is not record for any specific date.

I want records as :

```html
created_on | name
-----------------------
2018-01-01 | ABC
2018-01-02 | XYZ
2018-01-03 | MNO
...
...
2018-01-30 | FAQ
2018-01-31 | PQR
```

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select * from 'table' where 'created_on' like '2018-01-%'
```

Comment: but this will only return records for dates which exists in table. I want records from first to last date of current month, i.e 1st Jan to 31st Jan

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(CAST(`created_on` AS DATE)) = MONTH(CAST(NOW() AS DATE));
```

Comment: this query returns only those dates for which records exists. I want other dates to be returned as well, even if there is no record for that specific date. I want records from 1st Jan to 31st Jan, even if no record exists on any specific date

Comment: Please explain your answer code only answers are not ideal for anyone learning what is your code doing?